# I can't move my Testimonial Slider to the left

Tags: html, css, slider

I'm a beginner web designer and I created this testimonial slider using a template from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/maheshambure21/pen/qZZrxy). I incorporated it into my website built from scratch. I want to move the whole testimonial to the left , to make it kind of blend with the background.

I tried using the float-left property, and nothing happened. I also tried the margin-left property, and instead of the slider moving, the background became smaller. If anyone knows what I can do to separate the background, move the slider to left, please answer. I've been stuck on this for days, and this testimonial template is the only one that caught my eye. Here's the code:

```
<div class="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide1" checked="checked" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide2" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide3" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide4" class="slider__nav"/>
    <div class="slider__inner">

      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/90/37/01/903701985912184ea21c2f9afddabae3.jpg" class="testi">
        <br>
        
        <h4 class="slider__caption">        <i class="slider__image fa fa-quote-left"></i>   ethelpaw is exactly what I've been looking for! I am so grateful for the team to help me bring home my amazing kitty Luna.</h4>
        <p class="slider__txt">Alyssa Maguire</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="imgs/do-your-cats-know-any-human-words-mine-can-clearly-say-v0-khv0fzmo760a1.webp" class="testi">
        <br>
        
        <h4 class="slider__caption">        <i class="slider__image fa fa-quote-left"></i>   ethelpaw exceeded our expectations! They matched us with an amazing cat that fits our lifestyle perfectly. Their attention to detail and genuine care for the animals are truly commendable. Thank you for bringing so much joy into our home!</h4>
        <p class="slider__txt">Mark T.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="imgs/WhatsApp Image 2023-05-15 at 5.40.33 PM.jpeg" class="testi">
        <br>
        
        <h4 class="slider__caption">        <i class="slider__image fa fa-quote-left"></i>   The staff's compassion and knowledge made the adoption process a breeze. My kitten, Ginger brings endless happiness into my life. ethelpaw is a blessing!</h4>
        <p class="slider__txt">Sarah Johnson</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d8562814c131092f47d25eecd352a80df8bdd22a/0_404_7360_4417/master/7360.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=957f7591586da5045ffd305c7b09cced" class="testi">
        <br>
        
        <h4 class="slider__caption">        <i class="slider__image fa fa-quote-left"></i>   I adopted my playful and loving puppies, Tiger and Leah and the support I received from the team was exceptional. From the first visit to bringing my new buddies home, the experience was outstanding.</h4>
        <p class="slider__txt">Noah Collins</p>
>       </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
  .slider {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    appearance: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
  


    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
        -ms-flex-align: end;
            align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
  }


  .slider__nav {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 2rem 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    outline: 6px solid #ccc;
    outline-offset: -6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .slider__nav:checked {
    -webkit-animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
            animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
  }
  .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: 0%;
  }
  .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -100%;
  }
  .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -200%;
  }
  .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -300%;
  }
  .slider__inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
    transition: left 0.4s;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
       
  }
  .slider__contents {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
            flex-flow: column nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
  }
  .slider__image {
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    color: #85c4ba;
        
  }
  .slider__caption {
    font-weight: 500;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 2rem 0 1rem;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .slider__txt {
    color: #999;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    max-width: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;

  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes check {
    50% {
      outline-color: #333;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
      outline-color: #333;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes check {
    50% {
      outline-color: #333;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
      outline-color: #333;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    }
  }

  .testi{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    object-fit:cover;
    border-radius:50%;

  }
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the width in the .slider class since by default the width is set to 100%, and if you want to put something beside the slider you could just make a wrapper with flex or grid